# Add items from one form to another form listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a code. I made listbox modifier public on form2 and accessed it from form4 to add an item as button.text. But i couldn't get the item in the listbox on form2. Any suggestion? 
Thanks

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication35
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach(Control but in this.Controls)
            {
                if (but is Button)
                {
                    ((Button)but).Click += Form4_Click;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.listBox1.Items.Add(((Button)sender).Text);        
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very common error: _Form2 form2 = new Form2();_ creates a new instance of the Form2 class. This instance is not the same instance that you see on your display. You are adding items to this hidden instance. If you want to add to the visible instance you need to pass a reference to it in the Form4 constructor

Comment: Sorry but can you explain it? Thanks

Comment: To start understanding the problem add _form2.Show()_ after setting the listbox item. You will see another copy (instance) of Form2 class and this copy has the listbox filled with your items

Comment: Yeah but it opens another instance. But i want to add the item to the form already opened. So the Main item is already added through a button click. Also that button click opened this second form. A button click on second form i need it to add item listbox on first form but next down to Main item.

Comment: In the duplicate are explained the two main ways to achieve your goal. 1) Pass the instance of the first form to the second form constructor, use that instance to add items. 2) Pass, to the second form, a delegate to a method in the first form. The second form calls this method through the delegate and the first form updates itself (a better approach in OOP terms)